# template function returning template class - gcc compilation issue - error: expected unqualified-id before '<' token

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, compiler-errors

I am trying to implement a basic 2D vector class in C++ using a template based approach.
My class looks like

```
template <typename T>
class Vector2 {
public:
union {
    struct {
        T x,y;
    };
    struct {
        T lon, lat;
    };
};

Vector2():x(0), y(0)   {}
Vector2(const T c):x(c), y(c) {}
Vector2(const Vector2<T> & v):x(v.x), y(v.y){}
Vector2(const T _x, const T _y):x(_x), y(_y) {}
};
```

Now I wanted to add some operators like

```
inline template <typename T> Vector2<T> operator + (const Vector2<T>& a, const Vector2<T>& b){return Vector2<T>(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y);}
```

For development I am using currently XCode and Apple's LLVM Compiler compiles everything. As I need to compile additionally on a Linux System I want to use gcc too. But both on my Linux System(Fedora, with gcc version 4.1.2) and my mac(also gcc version 4.1.2) compilation fails, and I get the error

error: expected unqualified-id before '<' token

The same error happens for my little template based helper functions

```
inline template<typename T> Vector2<T> vector2Lerp(const Vector2<T>& A, const Vector2<T>& B,
                                    const Vector2<T>& C, const Vector2<T>& D, const double x, const double y)
{
    // use two helper Points
    Vector2<T> P(A + x * (B - A));
    Vector2<T> Q(C + x * (D - C));

    // interpolate between helper Points
    return P + y * (Q - P);
}
```

So my question is, if somebody might help me to solve this issue.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Before I start examining your code - that compiler is very old, I think you should upgrade it if you can

Answer (score 4):

You're using the `inline` keyword in the wrong place. You should introduce template parameters before you use it:

```
template <typename T> inline Vector2<T> operator + (....);
```

Note that function templates are `inline` by default, so you can omit it.